# How to check if 2 strings are alike by using recursion?

Tags: java

For example

```
check("abs","abc");// Return true
check("ab","ac");// Return false
check("ab","abc");// Return false
```

How would you write this method recursively

```
      public static boolean check(String s1, String s2) {
if (s1.equals(s2)) {
return 1;
if (s1.length < s2.length) {
return 0;
if (s1.length > s2.length) {
return 0;
if (s1.length == s2.length) {
for (int i; i< s1.length; i++){
if(s1.charAt[i].equalss2.charAt[i]) {
return 1

    ??
    }
```

I made a few changes and tried to approach first by myself but i dont know if this code will compile or do what i want it to do.

Comment: Your example shows 'check("abs","abc")' returning both true and false.

Comment: 1st and 3rd examples are the same but first prints true, 3rd false??

Comment: I hope you realize that you need to name your parameters something other than `1` and `2`. Those are not legal identifiers in Java.

Answer (score 1):

[Recursion:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#Formal_definitions_of_recursion)

> In mathematics and computer science, a class of objects or methods exhibit recursive behavior when they can be defined by two properties:

```
A simple base case (or cases), and
A set of rules which reduce all other cases toward the base case.
```

So you have define those two properties and implement it in the method.
Such a base case is often defined on some special values like `0` or `""`.

In your example you may define what happens when both strings are `""`. (base case)

The other property must lead to the base case, means by this rule you must reach the base case. In your case the empty string `""`.

This property may be some kind of [substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29)-operation which will lead to `""` (base case). So this rule may be: If the first character and the remaining string (recursion via `check(remaining string`) are equal, the strings are equal.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use recursion, you can achieve this by using this

```
public static boolean check(String s1, String s2) {
    int count = 0;
    if (s1.length() != s2.length()) {
        return false;
    else {
       for (int i=0; i< s1.length(); i++){
           if(s1.charAt(i) != s2.charAt(i)) 
                return false;
           count = i;
       }
       if(count == s1.length()-1)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It's obviously homework so he's not allowed to do this. But regardless, let's not spoon feed him an answer til he shows us he's done at least some work trying to solve this. Let's not encourage lazy behavior on his part.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to do this because it's an assignment, not because it's a good idea. :) So I'm not going to write the code for you, but the logic would be this:

- If both strings are empty, they are equal
- If both strings have a first character, then they are equal if the first characters are equal and the remainder of the strings are equal (recursive step)
- Otherwise the strings are not equal

Answer (score 0):

You normally wouldn't write this recursively, but if you really insist, the obvious method would be to compare the first characters of the strings, and (recursively) the rest (and the return value is the logical `and` of the two). When/if you get to the end (empty strings) those are also equal.